# The command php artisan test isn't caught by xdebug

Tags: php, laravel, testing, xdebug

I'm struggling with the following behavior:

If I execute `php ./vendor/bin/phpunit` Xdebug will caught any breakpoint I set in the Visual Studio Code.

Otherwise, If I execute `php artisan test` breakpoints are bypassed.

Ps: XDebug caught the artisan's first line file when I'm using both commands but my test files ( that are in the tests folder) are caught only by `php ./vendor/bin/phpunit`

I'm using:

```
PHP 7.3.9.
Xdebug v2.9.0.
Laravel/framework: 7.0.
OS: Mac OS Catalina
Web Server: Mamp PRO
```

My XDEBUG settings:

```
MAMP_Xdebug_MAMPzend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.9/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/Applications/MAMP/tmp"
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: What are your xdebug settings?

Comment: Hi!

MAMP_Xdebug_MAMPzend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.9/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/Applications/MAMP/tmp"

Answer (score 0):

I think your command line PHP is not the one from MAMP.

Mac OS has its own version installed. Compare the exact version of your MAMP server and your CLI version.

Try the full path to your MAMP PHP:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.9/bin/php artisan test
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it doesn't work yet :/

Comment: @RomuloSousa but the full path works (except xdebug)? The path was a guess

Comment: Yes, full path evaluates but without xdebug

Comment: I suppose there is a calling to php binary under the hood that disable this when calling php artisan test. Just a guess tho.

Comment: just the be sure: your breakpoints are reachable? have you tried to set a breakpoint at the first line of ./artisan?

Comment: Btw, php artisan test is much fast than php ./vendor/bin/phpunit

Comment: It worked on artisan file! I don't know why it doesn't reach to my test files. In fact, my breakpoints are reachable :/ . My tests are being done using the same breakpoints: One works and the another command not.

Comment: then debug from the artisan file to your test file. I am pretty sure you missed something and it is not executed.

Comment: I think phpunit's php path could be the reason. If I run: `./vendor/bin/phpunit` breakpoints are bypassed. If I run `php ./vendor/bin/phpunit` everything works!

Comment: I have to repeat myself. Check if you use the same PHP executable! 
echo PHP_BINARY;die();